# How to setup Avalanche Blockchain(PoS) nodes in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, blockchain

Avalanche, a blockchain that uses PoS(Proof of Stake), is an incredibly lightweight protocol, so the minimum computer requirements are quite modest:

- Hardware: CPU > 2 GHz, RAM > 4 GB, Storage > 10 GB free space
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04/20.04

That blockchain protocol has released a node program in binary. And I just need to run this binary file. So I will need the command line access, too.

May I know how to setup such blockchain nodes in AWS ?
Should I use EC2 or ECS or VPC or Elastic beanstalk or Lightsail ?

And how to expose that node's IP and port so AWS Lambda functions can call on it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, I found the answer from Avalanche's blog page!
https://medium.com/avalabs/setting-up-an-aws-instance-with-avalanche-1effec72c666